# Convert following code's output from html to json

Tags: php, json, rest, magento

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set("display_errors",'On');
$rootDir = ""; // Root Directory Path
include($rootDir."app/Mage.php");
Mage::app("default");
$rootcatId= Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId(); // get default
store root category id
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($rootcatId); // else use default category id =2
function show_categories_tree($categories) {
$array= '<ul>';
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
    $count = $cat->getProductCount();
    $array .= '<li>'.'<a href="' . Mage::getUrl($cat->getUrlPath()). '">' .$category->getName() . "(".$count.")</a>\n";
    if($category->hasChildren()) {
        $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category->getId());
        $array .= show_categories_tree($children);
    }
    $array .= '</li>';
}
return $array . '</ul>';
}
echo show_categories_tree($categories);
?>
```

I am getting output like
[image: Output Tree]

I want output of following code in json array format.So that it can be usable for android webservice.

Comment: i know json encode() but i want in same tree format.

Comment: @AbhishekMishra `json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

You need extract `data` and `view`. If you will have `clean` array in `$array` variable you can use `json_encode()`. For a `html` view you will can crate method `html_encode()` and add html's tags for data in it.

For example:

```
<?php
...
function show_categories_tree($categories, $view)
{
    $arrayCategories = categoriesConvertToArray($categories);
    switch ($view) {
        case 'json':
            return jsonView($arrayCategories); //Need array for json_encode
            break;
        case 'html':
            return htmlView($arrayCategories);
            break;
        default:
            return 'Error view';
    }
}

/**
 * Convert categories data to array
 * @return array
 */
function categoriesConvertToArray($categories)
{
    // Convert categories to array
}

function htmlView(array $categories)
{
    //Create html from array
}

function jsonView(array $categories)
{
    return json_encode($categories, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}

echo show_categories_tree($categories, 'json');
echo show_categories_tree($categories, 'html');
```

If you want to add `xml`, need just add a new method `xmlView`

Comment: Can you show me a peice of code what are you are saying..i m lii big confused with these things